# iboutlet & ibaction connection errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In my Xcode project I'm facing this issue with my IBOutlet and was wondering if anyone could help this troubleshoot.

its whenever I connect it only shows acton it also won't let me click and drag. Is there any way to fix this issue?

`@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!`

[image]

as you can see the connection won't allow me to change its grayed out.

How to fix this frustrating issue?

Comment: Please check your target, file to which you are trying to create a connection. File owner or nib class may not be set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The objective is a bit unclear, however it seems you are trying to connect an IBOutlet in code with an exit IBAction in the IDE. This is not going to be possible. Either create a proper IBAction function for use with a manual unwind segue, make a normal action method, or simply point a proper object at the IBOutlet as needed.  To review how to do this properly just use the Help > Xcode Help in Xcode to configure this correctly.  For more info on making an unwind segue check out the [technote](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2298/_index.html).

[image: outlet]

[image: action]